# Don't or doesn't

Tags: lyrics

*With some **little boy** in blue*

*Who **don't** know you like I do*

--

Why **don't**? Does it have any secret content?

Song: Elliott Smith - Between The Bars

Comment: Related [Is “she don't” sometimes considered correct form?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/108285/)

Answer (score 2):

*Don't* in the third person is very common in many non-standard varieties of English round the world. Popular songs often make use of these varieties.

Answer (score 1):

There are many dialects of English that conjugate both the to do verb and the to be verb "incorrectly." In my extended family, I often hear all of the following:

> He don't
> We wasn't
> You wasn't

When I was quite young, I removed these from my idiolect, because I wanted to speak in a higher [register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_(sociolinguistics)). The lyrics of this song may simply be written in the songwriter's natural dialect or may be purposely used to give the impression of writing in a specific dialect.

Answer (score 0):

***Songs!***

They use 'different English' if not *bad!*

In songs, it is common. One of my favorite songs too has it. Check here: https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/michaeljackson/whoisit.html

She don't....she don't... is heard many times. As [the answer here says](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/108285/is-she-dont-sometimes-considered-correct-form), it's lyrical English and everything is *fair there!*