# She don't love you no more! (Toy Story 3)

Tags: dialect, third-person-singular

Why did Lotso say

> [She don't love you no more!](https://www.quotes.net/mquote/130199)

instead of "She doesn't love you anymore" in Toy Story 3?

Does he speak unusual English?

Comment: Partial duplicates/related: [Is “she don't” sometimes considered correct form?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/108285/36187); [How is double negation interpreted in English?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/829/36187)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is non-standard English.  (Both the use of "don't" rather than "doesn't", and the double negative of "don't . . . no more".)  In movies this type of English is often used to indicate a person with little formal education.